# node-libxml-xsd fails with "...xmljs.node: file not recognized: File format not recognized" when doing a node-gyp rebuild

Tags: node.js, docker, meteor, node-gyp

When trying to create a Docker container for a Meteor app, **node-gyp rebuild** fails when trying to compile **node-libxml-xsd** with the following error:

```
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/node-libxml-xsd.node
/home/docker/data/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/libxmljs-mt/build/Release/xmljs.node: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Release/obj.target/node-libxml-xsd.node] Error 1
node-libxml-xsd.target.mk:133: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/node-libxml-xsd.node' failed
make: Leaving directory '/home/docker/data/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/libxml-xsd/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.93-boot2docker
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/docker/data/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/libxml-xsd
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! libxml-xsd@0.5.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the libxml-xsd@0.5.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I'm building it on a Mac (boot2docker) using Node 8.9.4. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, so I'm posting for posterity:

Turns out libxml-xsd doesn't rebuild libxmljs-mt first, so prior to running npm install, I need to run:

```
cd npm && npm rebuild --unsafe-perm libxmljs-mt
```